# Emacs function to create new terminal

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

Each time I open a new terminal in Emacs "M-x term" I get the currently open one, to get around this I need to rename the buffer where the terminal is running upon and then start a new one through M-x term.

I would like to write a function which holds a global counter and uses it to start a new terminal using it to generate the buffer name; once done I could map this function to a key binding of my preference.

I am having issues in running the terminal in a new created buffer, I am not an experienced ELisp programmer and this code might look quite naive to some, nonetheless this where I am at the moment :

```
 (defvar counter 0)
    (defun mine/open-terminal ()
      "Open a new terminal and rename the buffer"
      (setq counter (+ counter 1))
      (setq title (concat "Terminal-" (number-to-string counter)))
      (setq terminal (get-buffer-create title))
```

That function creates a new buffer with the correct name - although it does not show up it immediately as I would like it to do, the rub is that if I add at the end of the function the line:

```
(term "/bin/bash")
```

A new buffer called terminal is created, I have the feeling I am missing a bit here, is there a way to start a new terminal giving to it a buffer name ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here is what I use to create successively numbered custom scratch buffers, which you can modify to open a new term:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16493/2287

Comment: I see that the function `term` is just a few lines long -- so go ahead and find the function, open it up, copy it to your `.emacs`, and create a new function with a different name incorporating a concept similar to the link in the first comment:  `M-x find-function RET term RET`.  When you programmatically loop through or search for existing buffers with a particular name, that obviates the need to store buffer object/name information in a global variable. The latter is possible, but appears to be necessary unless the variable will later be used for other things not specified in the question.

Comment: @lawist: I can't find the function source .. I get an -> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Can't find library term")

Comment: `(require 'term)` in the `.emacs` or `M-x eval-expression RET (require 'term) RET`.

Comment: find-library-name: Can't find library /usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/term.el
 :-( Thanks for the link, even though it looks to me that we are trying to do different things, in your case you create a new buffer and you the mode to it, in my case I kind of need to run a process on it, again, I am far from being an expert.

Comment: Some people install a partial/minimal installation of Emacs -- the full version comes with all the sources.  You may wish to consider installing the full version of Emacs with all `elisp` source code.  It's possible you only have the byte-compiled `elc` source-code, which *ordinary* humans can't read.

Comment: Found the source there, and problem solved, thanks ! https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/5b5403289888efe8783ae6a405845b925f544ec1/lisp/term.el

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it I have found so far was it to literally copy the source code of the original term function from :

[term.el source](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/5b5403289888efe8783ae6a405845b925f544ec1/lisp/term.el)

And modify it into:

```
;; My terminal stuff
(defvar counter 0)
(defun my/open-terminal ()
  "Open a new terminal and rename the buffer"
  (interactive)
  (setq counter (+ counter 1))
  (setq title (concat "Terminal-" (number-to-string counter)))
  (setq buf-title (concat "*" title "*"))
  (message buf-title)
  (set-buffer (make-term title "/bin/bash"))
  (term-mode)
  (term-char-mode)
  (switch-to-buffer buf-title)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can have a look at `sane-term` package. It has `sane-term-create` (create new term) and `sane-term` (loop through terms or create one if none.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach that does not use a counter attached to a global or buffer-local variable -- i.e., the counter is only let-bound for the duration of the function.

```lisp
(require 'term)

(defun my-term (program)
  "Start a terminal-emulator in a new buffer.
The buffer is in Term mode; see `term-mode' for the
commands to use in that buffer.

\\<term-raw-map>Type \\[switch-to-buffer] to switch to another buffer."
  (interactive (list (read-from-minibuffer "Run program: "
             (or explicit-shell-file-name
                 (getenv "ESHELL")
                 (getenv "SHELL")
                 "/bin/sh"))))
  (let* ((n 0))
    (catch 'done
      (while t
        (let* (
            bufname
            buffer
            (basename "term"))
          (setq basename (concat basename (if (= n 0) "" (int-to-string n))))
          (setq bufname (concat "*" basename "*"))
          (setq n (1+ n))
          (when (not (get-buffer bufname))
            (setq buffer (set-buffer (make-term basename program)))
            (term-mode)
            (term-char-mode)
            (throw 'done (switch-to-buffer buffer))) )))))
```